# How to add nodes on the axis in axis environment in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following are my code. I used the axis environment for better axis style. I try to add nodes at g^W=g^L, which is a point on the y-axis, but the axis environment seemes to cut off anything outside the axis. What should I do?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.2]
     \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=7,
        axis lines = left, axis line style = thick,  unit vector ratio=1 1 1, xtick={0,8},
        xticklabels = {$p^w=0$, $p^w=1$},
        ytick={1.5,3,5.5},
        yticklabels = {$g^L-\beta$,$g^W=g^L$,$g^w+\alpha$}]
        \addplot[mark=none, dashed] coordinates {(8, 0) (8, 7)}; 
        \addplot[domain=0:8, dashed] {1.5};
        \addplot[domain=0:8, dashed] {3};

        \node[black,right] at (axis cs:8,1.5){\small{$W=0$}};
        \node at (axis cs:8,1.5) [circle, scale=0.3, draw=black!80,fill=black!80] {};
        \node at (axis cs:8,3) [circle, scale=0.3, draw=black!80,fill=black!80] {};
        \node at (0,3.5) [circle, scale=0.3, draw=black!80,fill=black!80] {};
      \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A caption.}
\end{figure}
```

\end{document}

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you add

```
clip mode=individual
```

to the axis options, the diagrams (with `addplot`) will be clipped, but the nodes will not.

Otherwise, `clip = false` will avoid any clipping.

PS: you need a `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}` or whatever added, to avoid surprises...

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Just a question, what does clip mean?

Comment: `clip` means to cut off all that will go outside the axis range. Imagine a function like `1/x` which will go unbounded otherwise...