# tikz node exceeding axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, axis, clip

I have an axis environment in a tikzpicture with a straight line exceeding the axis. At the end of the line I add a node whose text partially also exceeds the axis and is clipped. Clipping the line is ok but the whole node text should be visible. I tried to use clip mode=individual from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302119/how-to-add-nodes-on-the-axis-in-axis-environment-in-tikz) but I didn't work. Then I also added clip=false to the node properties. But it didn't work neither. What is wrong in my code?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[clip mode=individual,
xmin=5, xmax=15, ymin=22, ymax=60,
]
\addplot[domain=4:14]{16.46/3.6*x} node [at end,anchor=south east,sloped] () {testtesttest};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `clip mode=individual` means that the paths added by `addplot` will be clipped, and the others no. So you can do something like this (defining functions can help to streamline it, but this is the idea): replicate the line with an (invisible) path and plot the label along it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[clip mode=individual,
xmin=5, xmax=15, ymin=22, ymax=60,
]
\addplot[domain=4:14]{16.46/3.6*x}; 
\path (6, {16.46/3.6*6}) --  (14, {16.46/3.6*14}) node [at end,anchor=south east,sloped] () {testtesttest};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Maybe `\addplot[domain=4:14]{16.46/3.6*x} coordinate[pos=0] (p0) coordinate[pos=1] (p1); 
\path (p0) --  (p1) node [at end,anchor=south east,sloped] () {testtesttest};` is less painful.

Comment: @marmot yes, that's a great idea.